# Jquery datatables edit one row element and update db

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable

I'm building websites in laravel. I have formed datatable in which I have 5 columns and the 5th column is a button. When that button is clicked I want to turn 4th column element from false to true.

My datatable code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#orders-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! route('datatables.getorders') !!}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'full_name', name: 'full_name' },
            { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
            { data: 'number', name: 'number' },
            { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
            { data: 'completed', name: 'completed'},
            {
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<button onclick='Completed()'>Edit</button>",
                "target": -1
            }
        ],
        "order" : [[3, "desc"]]
    });
});
$(function Completed(){



});
```

I am calling the table like this

```
public function getOrders()
{
    return datatables()->collection(Order::all())->toJson();
}
```

I am not sure how can I access my order properties in button click function or how to update the database.

Comment: What is the primary key of an "Order"? Like what column in your DataTable is the PK for your database (assuming MySQL) table?

Comment: It is id, its not displayed in the datatable

Comment: You need to add it to the table even if you don't display it. Otherwise you can't update the database based on changed from your DataTable.

Comment: Okay i will do that. Should I search for something like updating database with ajax, could that work if implemented right?

Comment: I don't really know much about datatables, but I think the example here might give you some inspirations. https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/multiRow.html

Comment: @zerociudo this is more of what you're looking for. https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html

Comment: @bassxzero yes it is, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go simple way. Render the last column using id, and make it a button.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 0,//number of column you want
    "data": "completed",
    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
var str;
if(row.completed === 0){
str = '<a class="complete-action-button" data-id="'+row.id+'" href="/api/orders/makeComplete" class="success">Complete</a>'; } else {
str = '<a class="complete-action-button" data-id="'+row.id+'" href="/api/orders/unComplete" class="danger">Uncomplete</a>'; 
}
      return str;
    }
  } ]
} );
```

Make some api routes in laravel, that will handle jquery $.ajax. Use simple function on ajax callback to change the button url.

If you have problems with jquery functions, let us know.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how can I send the id or the object itself, I tried adding a slug like this: str.href += "/" + row.id; inside of the if but that doesnt seems to work.

Comment: You can use data-id attribute, pseudocode: `$('.complete-action-button').on('click', function(e) {e.preventDefault(); var orderId= $(this).data('id'); ...ajax...callback..changing url/class...`

Comment: or sure, as you say, prepare right url with id in laravel and check there record status, easier :)

Comment: Can i use the str.href attribute, because it gives me nothing, not sure how to change it. Edit: ah I finally did it, thanks for help

Comment: Glad youve made it. For attributes use jQuery attr method.